# Activiti Job Executor problem with async serviceTasks (activiti >= 5.17)

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

Please consider the following diagram

[image]

**MyProcess.bpmn**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="evl" name="Evaluation"></userTask>
    <boundaryEvent id="timer_event_autocomplete" name="Timer" attachedToRef="evl" cancelActivity="false">
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDate>PT2S</timeDate>
      </timerEventDefinition>
    </boundaryEvent>
    <serviceTask id="timer_service" name="Timed Autocomplete" activiti:async="true" activiti:class="com.example.service.TimerService"></serviceTask>
    <serviceTask id="store_docs_service" name="Store Documents" activiti:async="true" activiti:class="com.example.service.StoreDocsService"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="evl"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="timer_event_autocomplete" targetRef="timer_service"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="evl" targetRef="store_docs_service"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="store_docs_service" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
  </process>

</definitions>
```

To describe it in words, there is one user task (Evaluation) and a timer attached to it (configured to trigger in 2 seconds). Upon triggering the timer, the Timed Autocomplete async service task in its Java Delegate, `TimerService`, tries to complete the user task (Evaluation). Completing the user task (Evaluation) the flow moves to the other async service task (Store Documents), it calls its Java Delegate, `StoreDocsService`, and the flow ends.

**TimerService.java**

```
public class TimerService implements JavaDelegate {
    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimerService.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("*** Executing Timer autocomplete ***");
        Task task = execution.getEngineServices().getTaskService().createTaskQuery().active().singleResult();
        execution.getEngineServices().getTaskService().complete(task.getId());
        LOGGER.info("*** Task: {} autocompleted by timer ***", task.getId());
    }
}
```

**StoreDocsService.java**

```
public class StoreDocsService implements JavaDelegate {
    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StoreDocsService.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("*** Executing Store Documents ***");
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {

//        DefaultAsyncJobExecutor demoAsyncJobExecutor = new DefaultAsyncJobExecutor();
//        demoAsyncJobExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
//        demoAsyncJobExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
//        demoAsyncJobExecutor.setKeepAliveTime(10000);
//        demoAsyncJobExecutor.setMaxAsyncJobsDuePerAcquisition(50);

        ProcessEngineConfiguration cfg = new StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
                .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000")
                .setJdbcUsername("sa")
                .setJdbcPassword("")
                .setJdbcDriver("org.h2.Driver")
                .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE)
//                .setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)
//                .setAsyncExecutorEnabled(true)
//                .setAsyncExecutor(demoAsyncJobExecutor)
                .setJobExecutorActivate(true)
                ;
        ProcessEngine processEngine = cfg.buildProcessEngine();
        String pName = processEngine.getName();
        String ver = ProcessEngine.VERSION;
        System.out.println("ProcessEngine [" + pName + "] Version: [" + ver + "]");

        RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
        Deployment deployment = repositoryService.createDeployment()
                .addClasspathResource("MyProcess.bpmn").deploy();
        ProcessDefinition processDefinition = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery()
                .deploymentId(deployment.getId()).singleResult();
        System.out.println(
                "Found process definition ["
                        + processDefinition.getName() + "] with id ["
                        + processDefinition.getId() + "]");

        final Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        final RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();

        ProcessInstance id = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("myProcess", variables);
        System.out.println("Started Process Id: "+id.getId());
        try {
            final TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
//            List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().active().list();
//            while (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
//                Task task = tasks.get(0);
//                taskService.complete(task.getId());
//                tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().active().list();
//            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }

        while(!runtimeService.createExecutionQuery().list().isEmpty()) {
        }
        processEngine.close();
    }


}
```

**Activiti 5.15**

When the timer triggers, the above diagram executes as described. We use Activiti's `DefaultJobExecutor`
As we can see in the logs:

```
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl  - ProcessEngine default created
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.JobExecutor  - Starting up the JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor].
[Thread-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AcquireJobsRunnable  - JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
ProcessEngine [default] Version: [5.15]
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource MyProcess.bpmn
Found process definition [My process] with id [myProcess:1:3]
Started Process Id: 4
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.example.service.TimerService  - *** Executing Timer autocomplete ***
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.example.service.TimerService  - *** Task: 9 autocompleted by timer ***
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.example.service.StoreDocsService  - *** Executing Store Documents ***
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.JobExecutor  - Shutting down the JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor].
[Thread-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AcquireJobsRunnable  - JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor] stopped job acquisition
```

**Activiti >= 5.17**
Changing only the activiti's version in `pom.xml` to 5.17.0 and up (tested till 5.22.0) and executing the same code, the flow executes the timer's Java Delegate, `TimerService`, which completes the user task (Evaluation) but Store Documents Java Delegate, `StoreDocsService` is never called. To add more, it seems that the flow never ends and the execution remains stuck at Store Documents async service task.

Logs:

```
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl  - ProcessEngine default created
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.JobExecutor  - Starting up the JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor].
[Thread-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.AcquireJobsRunnableImpl  - JobExecutor[org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.DefaultJobExecutor] starting to acquire jobs
ProcessEngine [default] Version: [5.17.0.2]
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource MyProcess.bpmn
Found process definition [My process] with id [myProcess:1:3]
Started Process Id: 4
[pool-1-thread-2] INFO  com.example.service.TimerService  - *** Executing Timer autocomplete ***
[pool-1-thread-2] INFO  com.example.service.TimerService  - *** Task: 9 autocompleted by timer ***
```

- Changing to Async Job Executor. One feature of 5.17 release was the new async job executor (however the default non-async executor remains configured as default). So trying to enable the async executor in `App.java` by the following lines:

```
        DefaultAsyncJobExecutor demoAsyncJobExecutor = new DefaultAsyncJobExecutor();
        demoAsyncJobExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        demoAsyncJobExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        demoAsyncJobExecutor.setKeepAliveTime(10000);
        demoAsyncJobExecutor.setMaxAsyncJobsDuePerAcquisition(50);

        ProcessEngineConfiguration cfg = new StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
                .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000")
                .setJdbcUsername("sa")
                .setJdbcPassword("")
                .setJdbcDriver("org.h2.Driver")
                .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE)
                .setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)
                .setAsyncExecutorEnabled(true)
                .setAsyncExecutor(demoAsyncJobExecutor)
                ;
```

The flow seems to execute correctly, `StoreDocsService` is called after `TimerService`, but it never ends (the `while(!runtimeService.createExecutionQuery().list().isEmpty())` statement in `App.java` is always true)!

Logs:

```
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl  - ProcessEngine default created
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Starting up the default async job executor [org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor].
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Creating thread pool queue of size 100
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Creating executor service with corePoolSize 10, maxPoolSize 50 and keepAliveTime 10000
[Thread-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable  - {} starting to acquire async jobs due
[Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireAsyncJobsDueRunnable  - {} starting to acquire async jobs due
ProcessEngine [default] Version: [5.17.0.2]
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource MyProcess.bpmn
Found process definition [My process] with id [myProcess:1:3]
Started Process Id: 4
[pool-1-thread-2] INFO  com.example.service.TimerService  - *** Executing Timer autocomplete ***
[pool-1-thread-2] INFO  com.example.service.TimerService  - *** Task: 9 autocompleted by timer ***
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO  com.example.service.StoreDocsService  - *** Executing Store Documents ***
```

**!!!! UPDATE !!!**

**Activiti 6.0.0**

Tried the same scenario but with Activiti version `6.0.0`.
Changes needed in `TimerService`, cannot get the `EngineServices` from `DelegateExecution`:

```
public class TimerService implements JavaDelegate {
    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimerService.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        LOGGER.info("*** Executing Timer autocomplete ***");
        Task task = Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getTaskService().createTaskQuery().active().singleResult();
        Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getTaskService().complete(task.getId());
//        Task task = execution.getEngineServices().getTaskService().createTaskQuery().active().singleResult();
//        execution.getEngineServices().getTaskService().complete(task.getId());
        LOGGER.info("*** Task: {} autocompleted by timer ***", task.getId());
    }
}
```

and this version has only the async executor so the `ProcessEngineConfiguration` in `App.java` changes to:

```
        ProcessEngineConfiguration cfg = new StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
                .setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000")
                .setJdbcUsername("sa")
                .setJdbcPassword("")
                .setJdbcDriver("org.h2.Driver")
                .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_TRUE)
                .setAsyncExecutorActivate(true)
//                .setAsyncExecutorEnabled(true)
//                .setAsyncExecutor(demoAsyncJobExecutor)
//                .setJobExecutorActivate(true)
                ;
```

With `6.0.0` version and async executor the process completes successfully as we can see in the logs:

```
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.ProcessEngineImpl  - ProcessEngine default created
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Starting up the default async job executor [org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor].
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Creating thread pool queue of size 100
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Creating executor service with corePoolSize 2, maxPoolSize 10 and keepAliveTime 5000
[Thread-1] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireAsyncJobsDueRunnable  - {} starting to acquire async jobs due
[Thread-2] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable  - {} starting to acquire async jobs due
[Thread-3] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.ResetExpiredJobsRunnable  - {} starting to reset expired jobs
ProcessEngine [default] Version: [6.0.0.4]
Found process definition [My process] with id [myProcess:1:3]
Started Process Id: 4
[activiti-async-job-executor-thread-2] INFO  com.example.service.TimerService  - *** Executing Timer autocomplete ***
[activiti-async-job-executor-thread-2] INFO  com.example.service.TimerService  - *** Task: 10 autocompleted by timer ***
[activiti-async-job-executor-thread-2] INFO  com.example.service.StoreDocsService  - *** Executing Store Documents ***
[main] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor  - Shutting down the default async job executor [org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.DefaultAsyncJobExecutor].
[activiti-reset-expired-jobs] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.ResetExpiredJobsRunnable  - {} stopped resetting expired jobs
[activiti-acquire-timer-jobs] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable  - {} stopped async job due acquisition
[activiti-acquire-async-jobs] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireAsyncJobsDueRunnable  - {} stopped async job due acquisition

Process finished with exit code 0
```

2 Questions:

1. We have upgraded from Activiti `5.15` to `5.22.0` and we do not use the async job executor. Is there any way to keep the functionality of this piece of diagram to behave as it was behaving in `5.15`?
2. If switching to the async job executor is inevitable, then what are we missing in order to make this process complete successfully?

A sample project of the above can be found at: https://github.com/pleft/DemoActiviti

Comment: I have updated the description with activiti 6.0.0 test run. It "behaves" as expected. So what's the catch with >= 5.17.0 versions?

Answer (score 0):

Without answering your question explicitly which would require setting up your environment and debugging, I would recommend you at the very least move to Activiti 6.
The 5.x branch of Activiti hasn't been maintained for over 5 years and is effectively dead.
Even the 6.x line has pretty much been abandoned as the core developers have all moved to the "Flowable" project.
If you choose to stay with Activiti 5.x, your options are:

1. Maintain the codebase yourself (and hopefully contribute any changes/enhancements back to the project).
2. Contract Activiti support services. There are a couple of vendors offering such services.

Comment: Thanks but this kind of answer mostly fits as a "comment" rather than "answer". In my original post I have already indicated that with activiti 6.0.0 the async executor works as expected. Many thanks for answering though.